# find files matching pattern inside directory matching another pattern

Tags: find

Before I resort to writing Python to do this - there must be a way in bash with find or similar tools.  I want to search a tree, and find all files whose name matches a pattern, that are in a directory matching another pattern.  For example: all files named `foo_[0-9][0-9]` in a dir named `bar_[0-9]`.  So, I want all these files found (from the current dir):

```
a/b/bar_4/foo_02
b/bar_0/foo_03
a/b/c/d/bar_8/foo_88
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case, you can use the `-path <pattern>` option, similar to the `-name` option of `find`:

```
find . -path "*bar_[0-9]/foo_[0-9][0-9]"
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work.  Actually, how do I find any dirs named bar_[0-9], forget about the file part?  I can't find a "find . -path" way that works.

Comment: Then you can try `"*bar_[0-9]*foo_[0-9][0-9]"`. See `man find` , that `/` is not treated specially for this pattern. But you have not said that in the question, it curently says: `all files named foo_[0-9][0-9] in a dir named bar_[0-9]`

Comment: Oops, you were right, I messed up.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

In bash (and other shells with similar functionality) you could use *globstar*

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob

printf '%s\n' **/bar_[0-9]/foo_[0-9][0-9]
```